# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean under name airline_name

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts, struts-1

**`lodable.jsp`:**

```
<html:form action="DemoS" method="POST" focus="" >
    Program Name : 
    <html:select property="airline_name" styleId  = "tempId" onchange="onAirlineChange()" >  
    <html:options collection="airline_name" property="value" labelProperty="key" />  
    </html:select>  <br/>
    PART NUMBER
    <input type="text" name="part_no"id="part_number">
    YEAR
    <select name="year" id="year" style="width:200px">
    <option value="13">2013</option>
    <option value="14">2014</option>
    <option value="15">2015</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="Lodable" value ="OK">
</html:form>
<html:errors/>
```

**`DemoForm.java`:**

```
 public class DemoForm extends ValidatorForm{
    private String airline_name;
    private String part_no;
    private String year;
    public String getAirline_name() {
            return airline_name;
        }

    public void setAirline_name(String airline_name) {
            this.airline_name = airline_name;
        }
    public String getPre_part_no() {
            return pre_part_no;
        }

    public void setPre_part_no(String pre_part_no) {
            this.pre_part_no = pre_part_no;
        }
    public String getYear() {
            return year;
        }

    public void setYear(String year) {
            this.year = year;
        }

@Override
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request)
{
ActionErrors errors=new ActionErrors(); 
     if(getPart_no()==null ||getPart_no().length()<1)
{
errors.add("part_no",new ActionMessage("errors.required","part_no"));
}
if(getYear()==null ||getYear().length()<1)
{
errors.add("Year",new ActionMessage("errors.required","Year"));
}
}
}
```

**Extract of `Struts-config.xml`:**

```
<form-beans>
  <form-bean name="DemoForm" type="com.me.form.DemoForm" scope="session" />
<form-beans/>
<action-mappings>
 <action input="/pages/Lodable.jsp" parameter="method" name="DemoForm" path="/DemoS" scope="session" type="com.woi.action.DemoS" validate="true">
 <forward name="lodable" path="/pages/Lodable.jsp" />
 <forward name="save" path="/pages/success.jsp"></forward>
 <forward name="fail" path="/pages/fail.jsp"></forward>
 </action>
<action-mappings/>
```

**Collection:**

```
public Map<String,String> airline_name= new HashMap<String,String>();
airline_name.put("niraj.deshmukh","template1 ");
airline_name.put("user1","template1 ");
airline_name.put("user2","template2 ");
airline_name.put("user3","template3 ");
request.setAttribute("airline_name", airline_name);
```

**Exception:**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean under name airline_name
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1083)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:295)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(RequestProcessor.java:1027)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:374)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processValidate(RequestProcessor.java:995)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:198)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify path to the action correctly, should be

```
<html:form action="/DemoS"
```

Comment: I am trying to use form Validator but it is giving me above exception. If i remove <html:select> tag then it is working fine.

Comment: select is looks good, but options aren't, try creating a `List` property for the collection and use `<html:optionsCollection property="airline_namesList"/>`

Comment: not working giving same exception for airlline_namesList javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean under name airlline_namesList

Comment: you are not created bean property, not initialized, jsp contains errors you didn't fix it.

Comment: I think until tomorrow you can't answer my questions.

Comment: My collection i s type of Map<String,String>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34446/discussion-between-niraj-deshmukh-and-roman-c)

Answer (score 0):

check wether u have created constructor for formBean class or actionclass.if u have created constructor the jspcompler gives error like:javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class ProductFB.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I didn't mention the correct path to page which index page is navigate to and I used `jsp:forward` tag

Below tag which I previously used

```
<jsp:forward page="/faces/views/prime.xhtml"></jsp:forward>
```

and I changed it to `c:redirect`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
    <c:redirect url="/views/prime.xhtml"></c:redirect>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem was solved.